# How to execute TSQL select without blocking?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table which occasionally gets massive (300k+) amounts of rows inserted into it in a batch.

However, if the table is being read from during this insert period, the inserts and selects time out.

preventing all selects allows the inserts to run just fine.

Is there a way I can allow the `select`s to happen in a way that doesn't block the `insert`s?

I'm selecting with `READ UNCOMMITTED` but that doesn't seem to be enough.

I don't care if the read isn't 100% accurate (with regards the inserted data), it can miss rows if needs be, I just need the select to be fast and not upset the insert. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

NOLOCK - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026(v=sql.80).aspx

Does this help?

```
SELECT * FROM 'TABLE NAME' WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: isnt NOLOCK the same as READ UNCOMMITTED?

Comment: It should be the same, I use this over setting the transaction level to read uncommitted. I utilize this for when I have to read prod, however, we do use snapshot isolation as well.